# How to extract requires clause with a parameter pack whose parameters are related to each other into a concept?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I've got such a set of toy functions:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
requires std::conjunction_v<std::is_convertible<Args, int>...>
void test(Args...) { std::cout << "int"; }

template <typename... Args>
requires std::conjunction_v<
    std::disjunction<std::is_convertible<Args, int>,
                     std::is_convertible<Args, std::string>>...> &&
    std::disjunction_v<std::is_convertible<Args, std::string>...>
void test(Args...) { std::cout << "istring"; }
```

The first function will be called when I uses arguments that are all convertible to int and unconvertible to std::string, like: `test(1, 2L, 3.0, 4UL)`.

If there's at least one argument that is convertible to std::string and if all arguments are either convertible to int or std::string, the second function will be called, like `test(1, 2L, "Hello", 4UL)`.

And it does as I expected.

However, when I code the second function as the below two style, it doesn't work. The concept of arguments are checked one after another, and `1, 2L, 4UL` are not a `Istring`.

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
concept Istring = std::conjunction_v<
    std::disjunction<std::is_convertible<Args, int>,
                     std::is_convertible<Args, std::string>>...> &&
    std::disjunction_v<std::is_convertible<Args, std::string>...>;

void test(Istring auto...) { std::cout << "istring"; }
```

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
concept Istring = std::conjunction_v<
    std::disjunction<std::is_convertible<Args, int>,
                     std::is_convertible<Args, std::string>>...> &&
    std::disjunction_v<std::is_convertible<Args, std::string>...>;

template <IString... Args>
void test(Args...) { std::cout << "istring"; }
```

I'm wondering whether there's a way to extract the concept.

Comment: I am curious, why disjunction/conjunction and not fold expressions?

Comment: Oh I see.  `IString` is a concept in one type.  Not a pack.  `IString<int>` is another concept on one type.  Etc.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont About fold expressions you mentioned, I'm new to programming and haven't learnt such a use yet. Thanks for giving me a new idea anyway. And the `Istring<int>` problem is exactly what I'm talking about. I'm wondering whether there's a way to extract a concept that applies to a parameters pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `std::conjunction` and `std::disjunction` in such a case since it makes the code verbose and difficult to read. Using *fold expressions* will be more intuitive.

```
template <typename... Args>
  requires (std::is_convertible_v<Args, int> && ...)
void test(Args...) { std::cout << "int\n"; }

template <typename... Args>
concept Istring = 
  ((std::is_convertible_v<Args, int> || 
    std::is_convertible_v<Args, std::string>) && ...) && 
  (std::is_convertible_v<Args, std::string> || ... );

template <Istring... Args>
void test(Args...) { std::cout << "istring\n"; }
```

In the above example, `Istring` will only constrain a *single* parameter instead of the parameter pack, that is, check whether *each* parameter satisfies the following degenerate constraint:

```
template <typename T>
concept Istring = 
  (std::is_convertible_v<T, int> || std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string>) && 
  std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string>;
```

You should use the `requires` clause to check all parameters, for example:

```
template <typename... Args>
  requires Istring<Args...>
void test(Args...) { std::cout << "istring\n"; }
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/Kndv4r8ca)